# How to know when an activity is finished loading/being created?

Tags: android

I want to execute an animation 1 second after my elements appear on the screen. Is there a way for me know know when the activity is finished loading everything?

Comment: when setContentView() is called? Unless your doing some backgrounds stuffs to populate your views later.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089489/how-can-you-tell-when-an-android-activity-is-finished-loading

Comment: What did you try so far? onResume for example?

Comment: I didn't try anything yet. I want to know what's the right way to do it.